# Akka actor response caching

Tags: akka

i'm using Akka on one of my projects and i need to get the state of an actor, the way i'm doing it is as follows.

a REST request comes in

```
@GET
@Produces(Array(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
def get() = {
  try {
    Await.result((getScanningActor ? WorkInfo), 5.second).asInstanceOf[ScanRequest]
  }
  catch{
    case ex: TimeoutException => {
      RequestTimedOut()
    }
  }
}
```

on the actor i respond with the current work state

```
case WorkInfo => sender ! currentWork
```

for some reason the first time i call this function i get the correct value, on the following requests i get the same value i received on the first call

I'm also using DCEVM if that makes any difference.

Comment: How do you test it? Through HTTP? Maybe it is cached on the client side?

Comment: Could be but i doubt it. Tested using postman and IDEA's REST tester

Comment: Can you post the code of both the getScanningActor and the code inside the actor? My suspicion is that either you are not sending anything that changes the state between requests (and therefore you get the same result) or that your state-changing messages are sent to an actor that is different from the one fetched from getScanningActor, which will therefore always have the same state.

Comment: I'm not at home at the moment and will only get home on Wednesday but getScanningActor is basically a getter to a private val, no new actors should be generated.  I'll post the code when i get home

Comment: Aight, got the code. case WorkInfo => sender ! currentWork.setID(UUID.randomUUID().toString) is from the actor and private var scanningActor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[ScanActor], "Scanner")